# How can I use the #+OPTIONS: broken-links: option to ignore broken links, in a specific way?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, spacemacs

I have a very large orgmode document that has internal links to many different parts of the document.

If I try to export a subtree that has an internal link that points to a part of the document outside of the subtree exported, I get an error

```
Unable to resolve the link: "Determinism"
```

to get around this, I've written

```
#+OPTIONS: broken-links:auto
```

which makes it so that when I export the subtree, it can export *but* in the export the link's title isn't exported, it's simply a blank spot.

Basically in the original document's subtree I'll have this internal link that points to outside of the subtree like this

```
Philosophers love [[determinism]]
```

but upon export It becomes

```
Philosophers love
```

and what I want in the export is

```
Philosophers love determinism
```

I'm wondering if this is achievable.

I'm using spacemacs on MacOS, Mojave.

Comment: I see the same behaviour with `broken-links:t`.  This is not consistent with the documentation, which says the broken links are clearly marked in the output.  You should report this as a bug.

Comment: This seems to still be the case even with what I believe is the latest version of org-mode unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

As of org version `9.5-dev` in 2021 (and possibly earlier), the option

```
#+OPTIONS: broken-links:mark
```

Produces nearly the desired behaviour:

```
#+OPTIONS: broken-links:mark

* Test

Philosophers love [[determinism]]
```

[image]

The documentation for the customization option `org-export-with-broken-links` is:

```
org-export-with-broken-links is a variable defined in ‘ox.el’.

Its value is nil

  You can customize this variable.
  This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
  version 26.1 of Emacs.

Non-nil means do not raise an error on broken links.

When this variable is non-nil, broken links are ignored, without
stopping the export process.  If it is set to ‘mark’, broken
links are marked as such in the output, with a string like

  [BROKEN LINK: path]

where PATH is the un-resolvable reference.

This option can also be set with the OPTIONS keyword, e.g.,
"broken-links:mark".
```

There is no option to customize the appearance of the broken link. However, the function involved is `org-export-data` in the file `ox.el`, and it would be relatively straightforward to over-write the function if you want to tweak things.